# About tomcat port in web domain

Tags: tomcat, dns, server

I'm using tomcat to deploy my web app, but to access it I have to do it like this: mydomain.com:8080/my-web-app/list

What should I do to make it work only with mydomain.com/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the http connectors port number to 80, in [Tomcat_Path]/conf/server.xml, and deploy the application as "ROOT", by renaming war archive from "my-web-app.war" to "ROOT.war".